# SQLite Help: Need the date field in one table separated into three fields in another table

Tags: linux, date, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 on a Linux workstation.  In one table (A), there is a date field (YYYY-MM-DD) and in the other table (B), I need that same date to be separated into three fields (day, month, year).

```
CREATE TABLE A (
ID char(6), 
Date date
);

CREATE TABLE B (
ID char(6), 
Date_Day int(2),
Date_Month int(2),
Date_Year int(4)
); 

INSERT INTO A (ID, Date) VALUES (1,'2016-07-13');
INSERT INTO A (ID, Date) VALUES (2,'2013-06-01');
INSERT INTO A (ID, Date) VALUES (3,'2015-05-20');

INSERT INTO B (ID) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO B (ID) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO B (ID) VALUES (3);
```

The following script, produces an "Unable to get property 'substring' of undefined or null reference" error.  If I remove the INSERT INTO and just run the select portion of the following script, I get NULL values so either way, it's not working.

```
INSERT INTO B (
Date_Day, 
Date_Month, 
Date_Year
)
SELECT ID,strftime('%d',Date),
strftime('%m',Date),
strftime('%Y',Date)
FROM A

WHERE A.ID = B.ID;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  TIA

Comment: That error does not come from SQLite but from whatever language you're using to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `INSERT INTO B` with the following `SELECT` referencing `B.ID` does not make sense; what you probably want to do is `UPDATE B` instead (since you already inserted the rows with corresponding ids beforehand).

Instead of doing this manually, though, I would suggest you use a trigger on insert into A to insert the corresponding values into B. Actually, B is completely redundant so I would question whether or not it actually makes sense to use B at all -- it might be better to calculate the values in B on the fly when you need them (or define B as a view etc.).

Anyway, if you *really* need B, like I said, you could use a trigger like this:

```
> CREATE TABLE A (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date);
> CREATE TABLE B (
~   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES A ON DELETE CASCADE,
~   day,
~   month,
~   year
~ );
> CREATE TRIGGER insert_a
~   AFTER INSERT ON A
~   BEGIN
~     INSERT INTO B (id, day, month, year)
~     VALUES (
~       NEW.id,
~       strftime("%d", NEW.date),
~       strftime("%m", NEW.date),
~       strftime("%Y", NEW.date)
~     );
~   END;
> INSERT INTO A (date) VALUES ('2016-07-13');
> select * from A;
id          date      
----------  ----------
1           2016-07-13
> select * from B;
id          day         month       year      
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           13          07          2016
```

If you ever update values in A you'd also need to define a trigger for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date string has always the format *yyyy-mm-dd*, you can just use this statement:

```
INSERT INTO B ( ID, Date_Day, Date_Month,Date_Year)
SELECT ID, SUBSTR( date,1,4)*1, SUBSTR( date, 6,2 )*1, SUBSTR(date,9,2)*1 FROM A;
```

The substr function is documented here:
[SQL As Understood By SQLite / Core Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

The multiplication with 1 forces SQLite to convert the strings to an integer field.

Comment: *strftime* is part of SQLite's [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I stand corrected, you are right, still, the answer would be valid. I admit, your answer is better and gets my vote.